# 33% spacing with space between each div. Is it possible to condense my code?

Tags: html, css

To space things equally in CSS is relatively simple. There are also many questions on stack overflow pertaining to it, but one thing it does not explain is how to put spaces (or margin-left & margin-right) between each box.

To illustrate, this is what I would like to accomplish:
[image: accomplish]

I feel like I'm taking a long route by using three differently named divs to make this happen:

**CSS:**

```
#moreinfobar
{

}
#moreinfobarbox
{
float:left;
width:33.33%;
}
#moreinfobarbox-info
{
margin:0 20px;
background-color:#ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px 1px #000000;
box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px 1px #000000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="moreinfobar">

                <div id="moreinfobarbox"><div id="moreinfobarbox-info">Test1</div></div>
                <div id="moreinfobarbox"><div id="moreinfobarbox-info">Test2</div></div>
                <div id="moreinfobarbox"><div id="moreinfobarbox-info">Test3</div></div>


            </div>
```

I tried to get it work with two separately name divs to no avail. Is it possible to condense my code?

**JSFIDDLE:**

Three divs (WORKS):

http://jsfiddle.net/JsA25/

Two divs (BROKEN):

http://jsfiddle.net/TxT4T/1/

Comment: Remember you can only have on element with an ID! Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I feel is to just set the margin to 5%. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwbed/

Answer (score 0):

When you give Margin + Width to any child element when its parent has fixed width. Margin  creates outer space for the element - result: broken UI.

```
<div style="width:400px;">
  <div style="width:200px; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 20px;">One</div> <!--Total space required: 220px; [disturbed UI]-->
  <div style="width:200px; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 20px;">Two</div> <!--Total space required: 220px; [disturbed UI]-->
</div>
```

Parent has - **400px**;

Child elements are trespassing by 40px - **440px**; result: broken UI

You just have to decrease the width. In your case keep the `width:26.33%;`

Comment: Is there any way for you to revise your explanation of your answer? I'm not sure I understand it correctly and I'd really like to know why it's not possible to do with just two divs and keeping it 33.33%. Thanks

Comment: Edited - hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that the sum of the widths is greater that the total width of the containing element
(3 x 33,33%) + (3 x 20px) will always be greater than 100% !

You can do something like this instead:

```
.moreinfobarbox
{
 float:left;
 width:30.33%;
 margin-left:1.5%;
 margin-right:1.5%;
}
```

There is a good explaination of the problem in this article: [How to distribute elements horizontally using CSS](http://woorkup.com/2009/10/07/how-to-distribute-elements-horizontally-using-css/)